# Selenium automation with Firefox works locally, but fails on server

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Selenium automation with Firefox works locally, but fails on server

> Selenium version: 3.141.59
>
> Geckodriver version: 0.24.0
>
> Firefox version: 68.0.1
>
> JDK version: 1.8.0_171
>
> Local JRE version: 1.8.0_211
>
> Server JRE version: 1.8.0_191

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', ip: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
```

I am starting Firefox in headless mode. Works fine locally, but above error on Windows server.

Code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
    profile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.QueryInterface", "allAccess"); 
    profile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.frameElement.get","allAccess"); 
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\downloads");
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
    profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true); 
    profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true); 
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    options.setCapability("marionatte", false);
    options.setProfile(profile);
    options.setHeadless(true);
    options.setBinary(browserBinary);   
    options.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
    options.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);  

    log.info("Starting firefox");
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.getCapabilities().merge(capabilities);
```

Earlier I tried chromedriver and it worked well locally and on server. But I want to use firefox to download files in headless mode.

Browser trace log --

```
1563908741085   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "firefox/app/firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\<userid>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.cJQJoMJMqDtb"
1563908741101   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:62884
*** You are running in headless mode.
1563908741992   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1563908741993   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1563908741993   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1563908741993   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
1563908742164   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification profile-after-change
1563908742224   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1563908742271   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification command-line-startup
1563908742272   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification nsPref:changed
1563908742272   Marionette  DEBUG   Init aborted (running=false, enabled=true, finalUIStartup=false)
1563908742456   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1563908744415   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification marionette-startup-requested
1563908744416   Marionette  TRACE   GFX sanity window detected, waiting until it has been closed...
1563908802148   mozrunner::runner   DEBUG   Killing process 2704
1563908802148   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":""}}
```

Comment: be sure to set paths to firefox binary and geckodriver...   (firefox browser path may not be necessary if it's installed in a default location) System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", firefox_path); and System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driver_path);

Comment: Firefox is not installed on the server, I am using portable firefox (both locally and on server). Setting firefox here `options.setBinary(browserBinary);`, tried adding firefox binaries as well, but not working.

Comment: unrelated to your question but you have a typo here:  options.setCapability("marionatte", false);  (I think you can just remove that, it's legacy stuff anyway)   Did you set the path to geckodriver?... I suspect it's a path issue since it worked on one machine and not the other.

Comment: geckodriver path is correct, checked with `log.info("Driver: " + driverPath + " :: Exists: " + new File(driverPath).exists());` 
Added browser trace log. 
I am worried why it says `Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'`

Comment: I think you'll see this error if there is already a browser session open using the same profile.   Check to see if Firefox is already running.  Also check if both machines are the same as far as 32-bit/64-bit.  There are two different Geckodrivers... 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Could also be profile related, so launch without setting the profile and see if that fixes it.  If so you may be using the same profile on both machines?

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1068 . We had used work around options.addPreference("security.sandbox.content.level", 5) .

Comment: @Apurv - any luck fixing this issue?  I'm running into something very similar; can run a script flawlessly from my local machine, but not from an AWS server, although it gets a good part of the way through it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch RemoteDriver after - FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(your URL, capabilities);
```

Comment: My setup is not a client-server type. Its a standalone application that I want to run from server.